# Unable to link external Javascript with D3JS

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Please refer to think plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/2lvNHxvLEsNpVqNqmDUX?p=preview

I was trying to draw a circle using D3JS using javascript. My script.js file has the circle defined.

```
    d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width",50)
    .attr("height",50)
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx",25)
    .attr("cy",25)
    .attr("r",25)
    .style("fill","purple");
```

But it doesn't show up in the html after the D3 circle header. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@*" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>D3JS Demo - Drawing Shapes</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h3>SVG Bar</h3>
    <svg>
      <rect width="50" height="200" style="fill:blue"></rect>
    </svg>

    <h3>D3 Bar</h3>
    <script>
      d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .append("rect")
          .attr("widt ah",50)
          .attr("height",200)
            .style("fill","blue");
    </script>

    <h3>SVG Circle</h3>
    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" style="fill:blue"></circle>
    </svg>

    <h3>D3 Circle</h3>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the `script` after the `h3`,instead of `head`, like this:

```
<h3>D3 Circle</h3>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

No `body` element exists yet at the moment that your `script` is being executed. That means that `d3.select("body")` will be empty, if the script is run in head.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Xofci5Rm9XdpsP1zqu8a?p=preview

Comment: that worked and i will accept your answer but could you please explain why this worked?

Comment: you just edited the post with the explanation. great! thanks!